# Cron needs restart in order to process modified /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

I know there are many questions about this which say it will work right away.

Alas, at least on our newer SLES (Suse Linux Enterprise) 11 SP3 systems, that no longer seems to be the case. (You have to reload/restart cron in order to get it to realize that `/etc/crontab` has changed.)

I just tested it. You need to restart cron. Definitely.

This is what is installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i cron
cron-4.1-194.209.1
```

Seems to be ISC cron.

Man page says it checks the crontab every minute for changes and reload if necessary. That seems not to be the case however.

Anybody have any insight on this? Like cases where for some reason that could go wrong etc. Maybe it's a bug or the manpage is wrong, but that I can't imagine for now...

Comment: How are you modifying `cron`? If you do through `crontab -e` you do not need to restart anything.

Comment: I am talking about modifying /etc/crontab. According to the man page that should be a nobrainer too: `Additionally, cron checks each minute to see if  its  spool  directory's  modtime  (or  the  modtime  on /etc/crontab)  has changed, (...(`

Comment: So what? If you dig into the `man page` (and any `crontab` documentation) you will see that it needs to be updated with the `crontab -e` command, not manually.

Comment: You /can't/ update /etc/crontab using the `crontab` command. `crontab` updates the spool files in `/var/lib/spool/cron/tabs`. Whenever `/etc/crontab` was updated in the past, cron found out within a minute without any need to be restarted. I would only like to understand what changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not crazy. Suse have identified it as a regression which will be fixed shortly.